# Securing an iFrame form

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe

For our ASP.NET application we have an API which users can use to send data from their website forms (e.g. a sign-up form) directly to our application.

To use this, obviously some programming is required to connect their forms to our API. Some users (or their website developers) find this too difficult. So the idea is to provide a standard webform which can be included in their website using an iFrame. The webform should be unique per user, specified by using an ID or key in the URL or in a hidden field. For example, they can link their iFrame to an URL like https://myapplication.com/webform/CustomerID-1001

My question is how can we secure this webform? For the API we use an API-key, but that is used only serverside. Since the suggested webform is hosted in our application, the user cannot set anything serverside. So how can we prevent a malicious website visitor from copying the entire form (including the complete URL or hidden fields) from a valid user's website and using it in an iFrame on their own malicious website? (or at least stop the form from working in this case)

Do you have any suggestions about securing such a webform?

Comment: You could make it so the websites which want to use that form need to be whitelisted in order to receive a valid callback from the API

Comment: Sounds like an interesting approach indeed :)